# How does StoreKit 2 get download information for Apple hosted content?

Tags: download, storekit

I'm trying to upgrade an app from the original StoreKit APIs to StoreKit 2.  The app is currently downloading Apple hosted content.  SKPaymentTransaction.downloads is an array of SKDownload types that is used to get this content.  I don't see a similar variable in the StoreKit 2 Transaction struct.  When you make a purchase using StoreKit 2, how do you get the download information for Apple hosted content?